# setcookie function returning blank alert after clearing history on computer

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am working on some cookie functions and had my setCookie function working properly and had set it to display when Set Cookie button was clicked. I cleared my history on my computer when I was trying to get my get cookies function working -now all I am getting is a blank alert - can someone please help ?

```
 function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
 var d = new Date();
 d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
 var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
 document.cookie = cname + "=" + encodeURIComponent(cvalue) + ";" +      expires + ";path=/";

  alert("cookie is working");
```

}

```
 function getCookieTable() {


 alert("test2");
  var table =document.getElementById('tg-LTO9U');
  var rowLength = table.rows.length;
  var columnLength = table.rows[0].cells.length;
  var Cookiedata = '';

 alert("test3");
 for(var i=0;i<rowLength;i++){

   for (var j=0; j<table.rows[i].cells.length; j++) {
   Cookiedata += table.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML + ",";
}
```

}

```
 Cookiedata = rowLength + "," + columnLength + "," +              Cookiedata.substring(0, Cookiedata.length);
setCookie("myCookie", Cookiedata, 7);

  alert(document.cookie);
```

}

Comment: You need to provide some code along with your question. Right now there's no way to see where the problem is.

Comment: Apologies , this is code above . This code was working fine until I cleared my history - I added some alerts to test and everything is working but the alert(document.cookie) at the Bottom just give me a blank alert dialog box in jsfiddle when I run it

Comment: Can you describe what you do after clearing browser history? (Which I'm assuming also is clearing cookies...though in most browsers you can choose not to clear cookies: https://alssl.askleomedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/chrome_clear_browsing_data.png. Wish I could embed this image as opposed to using a link which will die at some point, this is just to illustrate clear history options in Chrome.)

Comment: Hi Peter, once I cleared my history I ran my code again - the code seems to be working but the alert box that had posted with the typical cookie data just posts blank - no cookie data even though it appears to go through the code okay. Thanks for link - maybe I should not have cleared full history but don't understand how it can be like this now

Comment: alert(document.cookie); this just posts out an empty alert now from the code above ? I really don't think anything else changed but if anyone can see anything with fresh eyes I would really appreciate it